# GrubX64.efi not found error

Tags: boot, grub, operating-systems, bootable-media, centos-7

Facing `grubX64.efi` not found with UEFI boot install.

I am using rufus to convert it to usb and the strange part is, EFI folder(iso) has the following files:

```
"BOOTIA32.EFI,BOOTX64.EFI,fonts,grub.cfg,grubia32.efi,grubx64.efi,mmia32.efi  mmx64.efi"
```

But in the rufus created usb. I find only `BOOTIA32.EFI,BOOTX64.EFI` in the EFI folder. Other files are not getting copied. I suspect this is stopping to boot in UEFI mode.

```
OSver:CentOS7.4(iso)
```

Answer (score 0):

Care to open an issue on the [official issue tracker](https://github.com/pbatard/rufus/issues) and post the **full Rufus log** of how you created the USB there?